# Rails NoMethodError when raking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I created a new Rails 4 app today. Something I've done many times. Created a basic User model seen here.

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
        VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
        validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
        validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
        add_index :users, :email, unique: true 
        has_secure_password
        validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
    end
```

I ran this migration with `rake db:migrate` :

```
    class AddIndexToUsersEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_index :users, :email, unique: true
      end
     end
```

My schema.rb shows that the migration worked:

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150714015826) do

      create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string   "name"
      t.string   "email"
      t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
      t.string   "password_digest"

   end

      add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

   end
```

But when I try to verify in the rails console to test the user model, I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method add_index`. I've tried just rolling back and rerunning the migration, but no change. The method is defined correctly in my `class User < ActiveRecord::Base`, and it migrated into the db.

I'm wondering if because I'm using sqlite3 for development and pg for deployment(heroku) that something could be messed up in that regard, but I'm not experienced enough on that front to know better. I can provide my gemfile if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be  using `add_index` in your model. That has no place there, delete that line completely.